# MVC action returning json object with a date field

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC action that returns JsonResult which I pass in a class where one field is a DateTime field. When I read that field in from javascript it's display like:

```
/Date(1391666400000)/

public JsonResult GetDate()
{
   return Json(DateTime.Now(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

How can I convert this to just say "2/6/2014" like it was when coming from .NET?

Comment: [Please please please... show your code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also see http://www.hanselman.com/blog/OnTheNightmareThatIsJSONDatesPlusJSONNETAndASPNETWebAPI.aspx

Comment: Erik this is such a small example I figured an explanation of what I was looking to do was enough, but I showed the simple example code above now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comments link better answers and explanations, but personally I just use a quick dirty javascript function like so

```
function date(s) { 
  return new Date(parseFloat(/Date\(([^)]+)\)/.exec(s)[1])); 
}

var jsDate = date(jsonDateFromDotNet);
```

Comment: Perfect thanks. Simple and to the point. I like answers like that!